# how to find killed zombie processes in linux

Tags: linux, zombie-process

I have a question regarding how I can check the killed zombie processes which are already killed so I need to check the processes IDs for further checking.

Thank you in advance,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

```sh
dmesg | egrep -i -B100 'killed process'

## OR
egrep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages
egrep -i -r 'killed process' /var/log

## OR
journalctl -xb | egrep -i 'killed process'
```

This solution may meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`KILL` signal terminates the program, there should not be any more of it left then so you don't have to check.

Program can ignore, different, `TERM` signal but I don't think there is a general way to track what program has received `SIGTERM` but it is not terminated yet. You would have to track this yourself AFAIK. Unix `kill` command uses `SIGTERM` by default.

More info: [Sending Kill Signals to a Process](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/806-4743/processmanagerusing-62/index.html)